# Visual Studio 2013 Visual basic create and write text file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to programming, and I have one small question. I wrote a code to create a xml file with 5 lines and everything works like a charm. Now I have a textbox and I want the input from the box, named INPUT be written in the middle of one line. This is my code:

```
Private Sub Entry_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Entry.Click

    Dim data As String() = {
            "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>",
            "<EntryQue xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">",
            "<NumberReq>0</NumberReq>",
            "<TypeReq>7</TypeReq>",
            "<Amount>", INPUT.Text, "</Amount>",
           }

    File.WriteAllLines("C:/Prog/xml/DATA.xml", data)
```

The problem is that the INPUT is written in a new line, between amount and /amount, like this:

Amount

123456

/Amount

How can I put it in the same line...for example Amount123456/Amount ?

Comment: vba<>vb.net.  vba is for excel, word, access, etc.  You will get more and better help by tagging it correctly.

Comment: "<Amount>" & INPUT.Text,

Answer (score 3):

Your array of string is delimited by commas, so each comma indicates a new line in the output file. Instead of this:

`"<Amount>", INPUT.Text, "</Amount>"`

Do this:

`"<Amount>" & INPUT.Text & "</Amount>"`

For details on the string concatenation operators (there are two), see here. I use the `&` operator because you are concatenating mixed data type (numeric & string):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx

> The `+` Operator (Visual Basic) has the primary purpose of adding two numbers. However, it can also concatenate numeric operands with string operands. The `+` operator has a complex set of rules that determine whether to add, concatenate, signal a compiler error, or throw a run-time InvalidCastException exception
>
> The `&` Operator (Visual Basic) is defined only for String operands, and
>   it always widens its operands to String, regardless of the setting of
>   Option Strict. The `&` operator is recommended for string concatenation
>   because **it is defined exclusively for strings and reduces your chances
>   of generating an unintended conversion**.

Comment: Works just like I need it to. I knew it was something simple, just didn't know what...thank you very much!